# Reportviewer VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, report-viewer2010

I have a report in visual studio from a program that I have coded. My problem is I want to sort my report by Department and then by SupplierName. However, my problem is that Department and SupplierName are in different datasets. So how do I sort with two different datasets? Right now my report just uses one dataset and in place of SupplierName it is SupplierID.

Report Example (AS IS):

[image: Report As Is]

Data Sets:

[image: Datasets]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is creating a dataset that combines both datasets.
Then just create your table with the same column headers and add your two sorts.

To add the dataset just Rightclick on the project -> add new item -> data -> dataset

I believe this would be the only way since the DataSets are associated to the Tables and any one table can only have one dataset.

Hope this helps.